# redundant systemd-journal-remote for systemd-journal-upload instances

Tags: linux, debian, logging, systemd, journald

I'm using **systemd-journal-upload** on serveral nodes to forward their journals to a single **systemd-journal-remote** sink, *loghost01*:

```
/var/log/journal
├── <foo-bar>
│   ├── system.journal
│   └── user-1000.journal
└── remote
    ├── remote-x.x.x.x.journal
    └── ...
```

This worked out the box for me on Debian 9 and systemd 232.

But I would like to have a redundant system, say *loghost02*, which works as a second **systemd-journal-remote** instance that also receives the uploaded journals.

Unfortunately, adding another URL to `/etc/systemd/journal-upload.conf` (on the uploading nodes) does not work:

```
[Upload]
URL=http://<REMOTE_IP_01>:<REMOTE_PORT>  # this is ignored
URL=http://<REMOTE_IP_02>:<REMOTE_PORT>  # this is working

# enable HTTPS
...
```

The [config docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journal-upload.conf.d.html) are silent on this issue.

How would I achieve redundancy in this scenario?